# Bootstrap JavaScript modal doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a button which would appear a details modal window, but nothing happens when I click on it. Would anyone please try to solve this problem? Thanks!

I have thoose script tags in the header section, and the rest of the code on detailsmodal.php

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade details-1" id="details-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="details-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Electron Creator Prusa i3</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="center-block">
                                <img src="images/products/electron-creator-prusa-i3.jpg" alt="Electron Creator Prusa i3" class="details img-responsive">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h4>Részletek:</h4>
                            <p>The Electron 3D Printer Prusa i3 (iteration 3) is the newest and most current 3D Printer design by RepRap Core Developer Prusajr. The i3 incorporates lessons learned from the previous two Prusa designs, as well as other popular modern RepRap designs. The release of the Prusa i3 under the GPL license and numerous other factors (its low cost, minimal BOM, simple assembly and calibration procedures, more than adequate documentation, etc) have encouraged the further development of a growing number of Prusa i3 “variants” worldwide, with different parts, different materials and different assembly processes, but which altogether adhere to the general looks, component assembly, dimensions and functionality of the original Prusa i3.</p>
                             <hr>
                             <p>Ár: 180.000 Ft</p>
                             <p>Márka: Electron</p>
                             <form action="add_cart.php" method="post">
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                     <div class="col-xs-3">
                                         <label for ="quantity"> Mennyiség: </label>
                                         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity">
                                     </div>
                                    <p>Raktáron: 3</p>
                                </div><br><br>
                                <div class="from-group">
                                    <label for="size"> Méret: </label>
                                    <select name="size" id="size" class="form-control">
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <option value="32"> 32 </option>
                                        <option value="34"> 34 </option>
                                        <option value="36"> 36 </option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> Bezárás </button>
                <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"> Kosárhoz adás </button>
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you link to bootstrap.css in your code ??

Comment: Yes, i have bootstrap.min.js linked in header section

Comment: i am talking about bootstrap.min.css !!! not bootstarp.min.js

Comment: haha sorry I was so tired when I answered.. So yea I have bootstrap.min.css too on my header section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details-1">Link to modal</a>
```

Comment: Okay thanks i had checked the code a thousand times, and I didn't notice that # is missing from data-target.